# How set 4 select tab dynamically with each other link using pure javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to set a calculator for finding quantities but unable to do so. I want to get color grade on select.
When selected color BLACK _ A GRADE are clicked, all three tabs (Ready | in process | Row) set dynamically to BLACK at all the three tab.

Please guide and help.

Thank you

```html
<table id="quantity">
 <thead>
    <tr>
       <th></th>
       <th></th>
       <th></th>
    </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
    <tr>
       <td colspan="1">
          <select onchange="calculate(); calculate1(this);" type="text" id="A101">
             <option selected>BLACK</option>
             <option value="15">A GRADE</option>
             <option value="10">B GRADE</option>
             <option value="5">C GRADE</option>
          </select>
       </td>
       <td colspan="1">
          <select onchange="calculate(); calculate1(this);" type="text" id="A102">
             <option selected>BLUE-PROJECTED</option>
             <option value="20">A GRADE</option>
             <option value="15">B GRADE</option>
             <option value="10">C GRADE</option>
             <option value="5">D GRADE</option>
          </select>
       </td>
       <td colspan="1">
          <select onchange="calculate(); calculate1(this);" type="text" id="A103">
             <option selected>RED-PROJECTED</option>
             <option value="20">A GRADE</option>
             <option value="15">B GRADE</option>
             <option value="8">C GRADE</option>
          </select>
       </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td colspan="1"><input type="text" id="A104" placeholder="BOX"></td>
       <td colspan="1">
          <select onchange="calculate(); calculate1(this);" type="text" id="A105">
             <option selected>CALCULATE</option>
             <option value="true">PREMIUM</option>
          </select>
       </td>
       <td colspan="1"><input type="text" id="A106"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td colspan="1">
          READY
          <select onchange="calculate(); calculate1(this);" type="text" id="A107">
             <option selected>PENDING</option>
             <option vlaue="0">BLACK A GRADE</option>
             <option value="01">01</option>
             <option value="0">BLACK B GRADE</option>
             <option value="01">01</option>
             <option value="0">BLACK C GRADE</option>
             <option value="01">01</option>
             <option vlaue="0">BLUE A GRADE</option>
             <option value="01">01</option>
             <option value="0">BLUE B GRADE</option>
             <option value="01">01</option>
             <option value="0">BLUE C GRADE</option>
             <option value="01">01</option>
             <option value="0">BLUE D GRADE</option>
             <option value="01">01</option>
             <option vlaue="0">RED A GRADE</option>
             <option value="01">01</option>
             <option value="0">RED B GRADE</option>
             <option value="01">01</option>
             <option value="0">RED C GRADE</option>
             <option value="01">01</option>
          </select>
       </td>
       <td colspan="1">
          INPROCESS
          <select onchange="calculate(); calculate1(this);" type="text" id="A108">
             <option selected>PENDING</option>
             <option vlaue="0">BLUE A GRADE</option>
             <option value="01">01</option>
             <option value="0">BLUE B GRADE</option>
             <option value="01">01</option>
             <option value="0">BLUE C GRADE</option>
             <option value="01">01</option>
             <option value="0">BLUE D GRADE</option>
             <option value="01">01</option>
             <option vlaue="0">RED A GRADE</option>
             <option value="01">01</option>
             <option value="0">RED B GRADE</option>
             <option value="01">01</option>
             <option value="0">RED C GRADE</option>
             <option value="01">01</option>
             <option vlaue="0">BLACK A GRADE</option>
             <option value="01">01</option>
             <option value="0">BLACK B GRADE</option>
             <option value="01">01</option>
             <option value-"0">BLACK C GRADE</option>
             <option value="01">01</option>
          </select>
       </td>
       <td colspan="1">
          ROW
          <select onchange="calculate(); calculate1(this);" type="text" id="A109">
             <option selected>PENDING</option>
             <option vlaue="0">RED A GRADE</option>
             <option value="01">01</option>
             <option value="0">RED B GRADE</option>
             <option value="01">01</option>
             <option value="0">RED C GRADE</option>
             <option value="01">01</option>
             <option vlaue="0">BLUE A GRADE</option>
             <option value="01">01</option>
             <option value="0">BLUE B GRADE</option>
             <option value="01">01</option>
             <option value="0">BLUE C GRADE</option>
             <option value="01">01</option>
             <option value="0">BLUE D GRADE</option>
             <option value="01">01</option>
             <option vlaue="0">BLACK A GRADE</option>
             <option value="01">01</option>
             <option value="0">BLACK B GRADE</option>
             <option value="01">01</option>
             <option value="0">BLACK C GRADE</option>
             <option value="01">01</option>
          </select>
       </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td colspan="2"> TOTAL QUANTITY </td>
       <td colspan="1"><input type="text" id="A110"></td>
    </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Please post what you've tried.

Comment: Where is your JavaScript?